# Powershell - How to Pass Variables to a regex in Select-String with Dot Star

Tags: regex, powershell

Basically i have a text file and i'm trying to grep (select-string) each line for the regex combination

```
VariableA.*VariableB
```

This should output any line that looks something like:

```
xxxxxVariableAxxxxxxxxxVariableBxxxx
```

And when i do it like this it works:

```
select-string "11568.*19521" d:\sourcefiledir\sourcefile.csv  | select -exp line | Out-File c:\destfiledir\destfile.csv -Append
```

What i want to do is pass variables into the regex.
So i defined two arrays

```
$ArrayA = @(23423, 45435, 234142, 24532)
$ArrayB = @(23423, 23423, 23424, 2342429)
```

and then do a for loop over the array slotting in the variables. But i cant's get it work. 
I've tried the following:

```
select-string -Path D:\somelocation\somefile.csv -Pattern "$ArrayA[j].*$ArrayB[j]" | select -exp line | Out-File c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

or without using the Pattern/Path switches

```
select-string "$ArrayA[j].*$ArrayB[j]" D:\somelocation\somefile.csv | select -exp line | Out-File c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

or with single quotes

```
select-string '$ArrayA[j].*$ArrayB[j]' D:\somelocation\somefile.csv | select -exp line | Out-File c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

or trying to define it as a regex variable

```
[regex] $regstring = "$ArrayA[j].*$ArrayB[j]"
select-string $regstring D:\somelocation\somefile.csv | select -exp line | Out-File c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

or

```
select-string -Path D:\somelocation\somefile.csv -Pattern $regstring | select -exp line | Out-File c:\somepath\somefile.csv
```

Basically i think it doesn't pass the variables through correctly to the select-string.. but i can't work out what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To embed complex expressions use a sub-expression inside the string: `$(...)`

```
$str = "$($ArrayA[j]).*$($ArrayB[j])"
```

A sub-expression can basically be an entire set of things to be executed:

```
$str = "Blah $((Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join '~') bleh"
```

You can use the format operator as well:

```
$str = "{0}.*{1}" -f $ArrayA[j],$ArrayB[j]
```

Or pre-create a variable and embed that:

```
$aAj = $ArrayA[j]
$aBj = $ArrayB[j]
$str = "$aAj.*$aBj"
```

Comment: awesome thanks briantist!! worked a treat!

If you have the time,... why is that the the array variables needed the extra brackets and $syntax as 
$($ArrayA[j]).*$($ArrayB[j])  ---works
instead of 
$ArrayA[j].*$ArrayB[j]   ---- doesn't work